# Camera Overlay Picture Black

Tags: android, camera, overlay

EDIT: As [Oren Bengigi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807038/oren-bengigi) suggested, I tried enclosing the bit of code that saves the data in a `post(Runnable)`, but I'm still getting the same results:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    void savePicture(final byte[] data) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.image);
                    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
                    b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + String.format(
                            "/SimpleBulb/%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis())));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am trying to take a picture with an overlay and save both as one .png. I am able to save the image the camera captures, and I'm able to save the overlay, but when I try to save both as one image, I only see the overlay and a black background. I've switched the two layers and the entire image was black, so the picture from the camera is just being rendered black. Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated. Here's my code:

```
package com.commonsware.android.skeleton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class SimpleBulbActivity extends Activity {
    private Preview mPreview;
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    RelativeLayout preview;
    Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // create a File object for the parent directory
        File imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SimpleBulb/");
        // Check if the directory exists
        if(!imageDirectory.exists()) {
            // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            imageDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Setup the FrameLayout with the Camera Preview Screen
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        preview = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.preview); 
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    public void snap(View view) {
        mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
      public void onShutter() {
          Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
      }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
      }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera _camera) {
          FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
                // outStream =
                // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
                // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
                // Save image to SD Card
                /*BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 5;
                String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + String.format(
                        "/SimpleBulb/%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis());
                Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length,options);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream);
                myImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, bos);
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();            

                // Replace view with Picture taken
                ImageView cameraImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.taken_image);
                cameraImage.setImageBitmap(myImage);*/

                // Save as one
                FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.image);
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
                b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + String.format(
                        "/SimpleBulb/%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis())));
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
      }
    };

 // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        SurfaceHolder mHolder;

        Preview(Context context) {
            super(context);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
            // to draw.
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            try {
               mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
               mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                                + data.length);

                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
            // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
            // important to release it when the activity is paused.
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }


        private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
            double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
            if (sizes == null) return null;

            Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = h;

            // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }

            // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
            if (optimalSize == null) {
                minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
            return optimalSize;
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h);

            Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.height, optimalSize.width);                           
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);                         
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);               
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    }

}
```

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bulb_pic" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="112dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/bulb" android:src="@drawable/litbulb"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="112dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:text="Snap!" android:layout_gravity="center" android:onClick="snap"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the ImageView that you set, doesn't update immediately.
What I would try is running the follwoing code:

```
  Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
            b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + String.format(
                    "/SimpleBulb/%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis())));
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
```

in a handler with postRunaable and see if it works.

Comment: Hey awesome! I really appreciate the suggestion. I'm really new to android, so could you please explain what a postRunnable handler is?

Comment: I have changed my code according to your suggestion, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: My guess was that the update to the image view still wasn't drawn,
The handler allows you to run code on the UI message loop.
Since it didn't work, you can try do it after the ImageView is redrawn.

Or, maybe just use the Canvas to draw a bitmap on top of the camera bitmap, but I'm not sure what exactly is your goal here.

Comment: Does the new code that I posted look like what you had in mind?

Comment: My goal is to just save the image from the camera with the overlay as one image. I checked out your website and saw that your one app, Face Costume, does just that. Basically I want my app to do what yours does when you press the button to take a picture.

Comment: With Face Costume I'm rendering the camera preview by myself, so it is a different story.

I have two ideas:
- When taking a picture the camera preview stops, so it can explain why it is black. Try doing it without taking a picture.

or

- The SurfaceView that is being uses for the camera cannot be grabbed from the drawing cache, since it is not a regular view.

I hope it is option one :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your insight. I moved the block that saves the image to the onClick method, and it is still saving it the same way. This really bums me out. I know people have done this, so I know it's possible.

Comment: If `getDrawingCache()` is an inherited method of `SurfaceView`, why can't it be grabbed from the drawing cache?